# Concept of attractiveness

Tags: creation, nature-of-man, science, fall-of-man, beauty

I want to ask why would God create such concept as attractiveness if He does not look at someone’s looks? 1 Samuel 16:7 ”for man looks at the outward appearance, but the LORD looks at the heart.”

Study after study shows that there is objective beauty which is symmetry and anything that has symmetry is considered pretty or more prettier than anything else. Also there are genes that are better and stronger and people with such genes tend to look pretty (symmetrical), think more positive, be very healthy and accomplish a lot of things. Weaker genes give the opposite and someone with such genes struggles.

It seems like before the Fall people were very symmetrical and had stronger genes but after the Fall the degradation happened. Also Solomon’s song is clear that people are designed to be attracted also to looks.

I just feel somewhat down because if God does not care about looks then why did He bother to do objective attraction like symmetry, better genes etc. I always thought that all the features that we have that are considered unattractive were just made that way by us because after the Fall we choose what is pretty and what is not and if we did not Fall we would not care.  But studies show something completely different and we are creatures attracted to symmetry which gives pretty features and in turn good genes because symmetry comes from them. Children are the best example, they tend to go to prettier symmetrical things, animals and people.

What do you think? Clarifying, I know that God does not look at our looks when it comes to salvation but still, He created people to find themselves attractive and He shows beauty in symmetry and proportions.

Comment: I understand the gist of your question, but you need to do some work to phrase the question to solicit an objective answer rather than a call for "what do you think"?  Stack exchange is not a discussion forum, please do the Tour if you haven't done so, and read about acceptable questions on this site.

Comment: So because I just asked what do you think my question is not acceptable? Really? Of course I want objective answer but I think if I did such small mistake you should not take it that seriously. Also I am looking for help from Christians and I thought it would not be a problem how I formed my question if someone needs help to understand something

Comment: Peace.  SE sites are *not* like help desk.  SE posters have responsibility to make their questions acceptable to community standard.  I didn't -1 your question, in fact I'm preparing an answer for you because the gist of your question is good.  But the Q needs to be tweaked and as a first timer myself several years ago, I did my part to learn through reading [various Help center articles](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) on Asking.  For C.SE, it's good to start with [what types of questions can I ask on this site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3409/10672)?.

Comment: even citing some studies would help. I found this [one](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6557895/) which seems to state the opposite, that there isn't objective attractiveness: `facial beauty seems to be more complex than symmetry, averageness and secondary sexual traits`

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. If the beholder loves, then the loved one is beautiful.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

#### Relationship of Beauty to God through Nature

All Christian traditions I know will work out these distinct but related concepts to God (several you alluded to in the Q) this way:

1. ***Objective*** beauty, with "source of truth" of this objectivity in God Himself, the source of all truths in things.  You named this "attractiveness", but I use a more common philosophical term that is more general to include other kinds of beauty.
2. God embeds beauty in nature, including humans, which theologians (unanimous in the history of theology) define the relationship as nature ***participating*** in God.
3. Human's ***appreciation*** for beauty, a capacity planted in human soul by God Himself.  This is the capacity to contemplate what is beautiful and what is not, using the measure of objectivity which our intellect participates in God's truth (#1) through the objects found in nature (because of #2) that we perceive by our senses.  It's a debate whether ONLY the *genes* are responsible for this, or is it the *soul* working itself out THROUGH the *genes*.
4. Human's ***pursuit*** of beauty, whether lawful or not, *also* planted in human soul by God Himself.  Thus humans beautify themselves and also make beautiful things as *imitation* of God's activity in nature.  You named this "attraction", but I use a more common term in theology.

Please pause for a moment and reflect on our own experiences as Christians to see how the above 4 relationships of Beauty to God makes a lot of sense, especially in light of God calling his creation (nature) as originally Good (Genesis 1).  So to answer one of your questions which I rephrase as follows:

> Why does God create objectively beautiful things (#1 and #2) AND God embeds the capacity for appreciation/pursuit of beautiful things in humans (#3 and #4)?

Answer: **Because God Himself is Beautiful** (one of His attributes) and He wants Nature to reflect this in order to be one of the avenues **to lead humans back to the SOURCE of Beauty who is God Himself.**  One of the ways we can praise and glorify God is then legitimately through **celebrating His beauty** by engaging in activities that appreciate and make beautiful things, like the many forms of arts and their museums, schools, competitions, and institutes.

#### Effect of the Fall

Now where the Fall comes in, there are many unknowns, but again, most theologians will say that the Fall does NOT remove humans' capacity to *appreciate* beauty but **make the *pursuit* of beauty *DISORDERED*** (though they were not as unanimous as in the previous section).  Several points follow from this:

1. It's a matter of speculation whether before the Fall there are "stronger genes".  In other words, whether the existence of genetic defects in babies today is caused by the Fall.
2. God does not change.  He appreciates Beauty before the Fall, so he still does today.  He also expects humans to trace every beauty in nature to Him, but the Fall clouds this awareness, thus many humans today credit *themselves* for the beauty they create WITHOUT including God in the contemplation (i.e. atheists).
3. What is truly heartbreaking for me in the Holocaust is how Hitler appreciates beauty (his many paintings collection and he appreciates Wagner) but develops this despicable doctrine of the Jewish people having inferior genes and deserves to be exterminated.  But before we quickly condemn Hitler we should also look at how the prevailing American culture today discriminates against babies with genetic defects, even abort them.  In contrast, several Christian parents become heroes and should be supported and commended because they loved their genetically defective babies, raise them to adulthood, and later on have their hearts transformed as they reflect on how God loved them as much as the genetically normal and that they are *participating* in this love.  Example testimony of a mother's heart transformation: [Carol Cross - Suffering as a Gift?](https://vimeo.com/179507680) (the testimony starts at minute 9:00).
4. It is legitimate and natural to prefer beauty, but these are a few ways showing the great temptation to make this pursuit DISORDERED:

   - When the ultimate end is glorifying self (or nation, like Hitler) instead of God
   - When the disadvantaged (because of their handicaps) are treated unjustly.  The OT is absolutely clear that God desires justice especially to the weak and the oppressed.  We have to include the genetically "disadvantaged" humans, the disabled, and those having serious medical conditions not through their own fault as among "the weak".
   - When a person's life goals elevate the pursuit of beautifying themselves above everything else (even with the rhetoric of God, such as prosperity gospel of health and wealth), thus idolizing what's otherwise a legitimate pursuit.

#### Conclusion

Your question starts with 1 Sam 16:7 where the context is when God was choosing the next king among the sons of Jesse.  Samuel was surprised that God didn't choose someone strong and handsome like Saul, but this story was preserved to us so we can learn the general principle that a **properly ordered pursuit of beauty** (ordering is in the "heart") is more important to God than beauty itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer. It helped me to understand many things about beauty and how it comes to God.

Comment: @LucyRed I'm glad I could help.  I tried to hit all elements you mentioned in your Q.  Let me know in this answer's comment space how the answer can be improved.  Otherwise, you can click on the "check mark" to indicate that this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

An old story goes: A child who got separated from his parents in a crowded marketplace, is brought to the palace.The king asks for the names of his parents, which the child is not able to recall. The king then asks the child how his mother looks like. He replies: "My mother is the most beautiful woman in the world".The king thinks he got a clue, and calls for the most beautiful mothers of his kingdom. The child cannot find his mother among them. Then, the king calls for the second best . Still no positive results. As a final attempt , the king calls for the most ordinary looking women. Yes, the child identifies one of them as his mother! The moral of the story is : Beauty is subjective. Even the case of symmetry is applicable only to a limited extent. In fact, no person has perfectly symmetrical sides of face. Computer-generated pictures of celebrity film stars prove that they would look worse if both facial sides are perfectly symmetric ! And we never look for symmetry in a rose flower in order to enjoy its beauty. The problem makers in fact, are the opinion leaders of the society who first decide who are beautiful and who are not . Others simply follow those leaders. Consider the images of Jesus we have. He looks handsome. But see that his eyes are unduly big  and his nose is a chiseled Greek nose ! And his fair face does not tell us  that he worked as a carpenter till age thirty and wandered through Palestine for the last three years of life on earth ! And there are people who consider it blasphemous to hear that Jesus was an ordinary looking person. So, if one doubts if  God desires that a limited part of his creation be beautiful with the rest being below the cut,that doubt is not 'fair' .